# Mechanize submit result is not the correct page

Tags: ruby, mechanize, scrape

I was trying to scrape booking.com as an exercise to learn Mechanize, but I can't get past an issue. I am trying to get a hotel's prices trough Mechanize using the following code:

```
hotel_name = "Hilton New York"
date = Date.today
day_after_date = date + 1
agent = Mechanize.new

homepage = agent.get("http://www.booking.com")
# Fill out the main form on the booking.com homepage
main_form = homepage.form_with(name: 'frm')
main_form.ss = hotel_name
main_form.checkin_monthday = date.day.to_s
main_form.checkin_year_month = "#{date.year}-#{date.month}"
main_form.checkout_monthday = day_after_date.day.to_s
main_form.checkout_year_month = "#{day_after_date.year}-#{day_after_date.month}"
main_form[''] = 1 # 1 adult, 0 children

homepage.save('1-homepage.html') # For debugging purposes

# Choose the hotel from the list that comes up
hotel_selection_page = agent.submit main_form
hotel_link = hotel_selection_page.links.select { |link| link.text =~ /#{hotel_name}/i }.first
hotel_page = hotel_link.click

# For debugging purposes
hotel_selection_page.save('2-hotels-list.html')
hotel_page.save('3-hotel-page.html')
```

If you follow the pages through your web browser, you will see that, after submitting the form on the homepage and choosing the hotel on the next page, you see the room prices for the selected date.

Through Mechanize though, on the `3-hotel-page.html` page, you cannot see the prices.

I have been at this for a while, and I can't seem to solve it. I thought the problem was the JavaScript that booking.com is using, but even after turning off JavaScript on my web browser, I was able to get the correct behavior.

Any thoughts on this?

**Edit:** I just realized that when the form is sent through the web browser, on the second page where you choose the hotel, hotel links have a `sid` parameter (for example, `sid=ba232d9d340c66ae73f1ded22b80a0da`), but when I send the form through Mechanize, I don't get the `sid` parameter. What could be the reason?

Comment: Look at the form in your browser. Everything with a name attribute can be set. Things like `main_form[''] = 1` don't make any sense.

Comment: @pguardiario Why doesn't it make sense? If you look at the form in your browser, you will see that their select box for "Guests" is defined as `<select class="b-selectbox__element b-selectbox__groupselection" name="">
(omitted)
<option value="1" data-adults="1" data-name="1 adult, 0 children" data-type="basic">1 adult, 0 children</option> (omitted)
</select>` To access that, I am using `main_form[''] = 1`. Obviously booking.com needs to clean up its markup, but I can't do much about it.

Comment: Right I understand why you did that but parameters need names which means you're overlooking something.

Comment: @pguardiario, can you elaborate it? Which parameter do you mean exactly? I am pretty new to this, I really cannot see the problem.

Comment: I'm saying that if the select doesn't have a name attribute it means it doesn't do anything in terms of what gets submitted.

Comment: @pguardiario How does it work on the browser then? Because on the browser it actually reflects your choice in the next page.

Comment: @hattenn I noticed that when the search form is posted, there are some fields added with regard to the number of adults and children: `group_adults:2` and `group_children:0`. What happens if you add these fields to `main_form` instead of the field that has no name?

Comment: @zwippie, I tried it now, but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @hattenn - just look at the url, it's a simple GET request.

Comment: @pguardiario, I understand what you mean now with "it won't get submitted if it has no attribute". I looked at the parameters, and I am sending the ones that are sent when using a browser, but I think the problem is related to `sid`. I'll explain it in the question.

Comment: First you'll want to confirm that `sid` is the problem and for that I recommend proxying your browser through charles, it will let you edit the request to see if that's really the issue. My feeling is that it's probably something else.

Comment: @pguardiario I changed the `sid` to `0` with Charles, and resent the query. It still worked correctly, you're probably right that `sid` is not the problem. I think this problem is above my current knowledge.

Comment: Ok well, you're halfway there. now proxy your Mechanize agent through charles and compare the requests. Somewhere between the two is your solution.

Comment: @pguardiario Ok, solved it. I changed the user agent, and now everything is working properly. Thanks a lot for all the help! If you can add your recommendations to an answer, I will be happy to award the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line to change the user agent worked in the end:

```
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot these things is to proxy both the Mechanize request and the browser request through a debugging proxy like Charles or Fiddler and compare them side by side.